# Google Sheets & GAS - Send an email when a cell is populated

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I am relatively new to GAS, but have been successful in other, similar projects in the past. I am attempting to send an email to a static address (mine) when "Past Due" is selected from the dropdown in row G on my Gantt Chart in Sheets. I've put the following code together from various sources, and have a sendEmail > from spreadsheet > on edit trigger set up.

```
    function sendEmail(e) { 
      if (e.value == 'Past Due' && e.range.getColumn() == 7) {
        var row = e.range.getRow();
        var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Gantt Chart");
        var emailAddress = "example@email.com";
        var subject = "Your Task is Past Due"
        var message = "You have a task that is past due. Please refer to the Yearly Work Plan for more information. DO NOT RESPOND TO THIS MESSAGE.";
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }
    }
```

When I select "Past Due" from the dropdown, nothing happens. I get no email, nor do I get a failure notification. I feel like this may be an issue with my trigger, but can't seem to wrap my head around how to fix it (even after several hours spent digging through forums, blogs, and videos).

Can anyone please help me sort this out?

Comment: Are you using on onEdit trigger? You can set it up for immediate notifications and it will send you any errors that it run's into in your code.

Comment: I am using an onEdit trigger (noted above). I have immediate notifications established and am still not getting any failure notices - which is why I'm wondering if the trigger itself is the problem.

Comment: Well you might just go ahead and delete it and recreate it.  Also you could create a trigger log with one of you sheets and append a row with a time stamp to it every time you get a trigger.  You'll need to put that in before your opening if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I used this little function just to test that onEdit will trigger when you make a change in a data validated column.

```
function sendSomething(e) {
  var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM:dd:yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var desc='This is an onEdit Trigger';
  e.source.getSheetByName('Logger').appendRow([ts,desc]);
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()=='RowAndCols' && e.range.getColumn()==2){
    e.source.getSheetByName('Logger').appendRow([ts,'this is the edit from RowAndCols','Current Value is ' + e.value,'Row = ' + e.range.getRow()]);
  }
}
```

In my case I used a named range with Yes No alternatives and validated ColumnB.

The was the output on my Logger Sheet.

```
12:15:2017 11:22:49 this is the edit from RowAndCols    Current Value is Yes    
12:15:2017 11:22:51 This is an onEdit Trigger       
12:15:2017 11:22:51 this is the edit from RowAndCols    Current Value is No 
12:15:2017 11:22:53 This is an onEdit Trigger       
12:15:2017 11:22:53 this is the edit from RowAndCols    Current Value is Yes    
12:15:2017 11:22:56 This is an onEdit Trigger       
12:15:2017 11:22:56 this is the edit from RowAndCols    Current Value is No 
12:15:2017 11:22:58 This is an onEdit Trigger       
12:15:2017 11:22:58 this is the edit from RowAndCols    Current Value is Yes    
12:15:2017 11:23:59 This is an onEdit Trigger       
12:15:2017 11:23:59 this is the edit from RowAndCols    Current Value is Yes    Row = 5
12:15:2017 11:24:00 This is an onEdit Trigger       
12:15:2017 11:24:00 this is the edit from RowAndCols    Current Value is No Row = 6
12:15:2017 11:24:02 This is an onEdit Trigger       
12:15:2017 11:24:02 this is the edit from RowAndCols    Current Value is Yes    Row = 7
12:15:2017 11:24:04 This is an onEdit Trigger       
12:15:2017 11:24:04 this is the edit from RowAndCols    Current Value is No Row = 8
```

The name of my sheet was RowAndCols and the name of my Logger sheet was Logger.

And it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but unfortunately I already know that On Edit triggers work *in general* within this spreadsheet (I have used them elsewhere during my experimentation). I hope to gain an answer to why the entire operation may not be working. Not sure why using script to do something as simple as send an email is such a pain, but it's kicking my butt.